# Weka ARFF error

Tags: csv, machine-learning, weka, data-mining, arff

I am new to Weka.
I am trying to run my arff file in weka and I keep getting an error.
java.io.IOException: Unable to determine structure as arff(Reason: java.io.IOException:end of line expected, readToken[LINKEDIN],line1)

I don't see whats wrong with the line and I have tried to format the file and declare the attributes as best as I can.

I have attached the file
[ARFF file.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hptd4avspnsh51d/FINAL%20LINKEDIN%20DATA%20%282%29.arff?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra whitespace from your first line.

You can also try adding quotation marks, but I'm not sure if that is permitted by ARFF